# AS3 split() command

Tags: regex, arrays, actionscript, split, combinations

Is there a way I can split by more than one character? I do not mean a combination of characters, but an array of specific choices. For example:

```
s = "john is tall,sue is small";
s.split(" ");
trace(s);
```

The output in this circumstance would be:

```
'john' 'is' 'tall,sue' 'is' 'small'
```

However, what if I wanted to edit out the comma as well such that the output was:

```
'john' 'is' 'tall' 'sue' 'is' 'small'
```

How can I do this? I'm pretty sure it's done with regex, but I'm a little lost.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS3's [`split()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) method accepts a regular-expression as input, so you should be able to use the following:

```
var str:String = "john is tall,sue is small";
var re:RegExp = /[, ]/;
var results:Array = str.split(re);
```

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. I haven't had the need to use regex in AS3, and now I know how!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need a regular expression that will match on `','` or `' '` characters. Very simply it is:

```
/[, ]/g
```